# how to replce empty lines with text using sed

Tags: linux

How to replace empty lines with text using sed? I tried some of the tricks posted earlier but it does't work. Could some body help me with this?

Example File content-

```
Linux is an os.

Linux is opensource

Linux has various flavors like fedora,centos etc.
```

I want to replace these blank lines with text like hello.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just match start-line then endline if you want totally empty lines only

```
 sed -e 's/^$/Hello/g'
```

If you also want to match lines containing spaces then

```
sed -e 's/^ *$/Hello/g'
```

Edit: a better variant if you want to match all lines containing only whitespace:

```
sed -e 's/^\s*$/Hello/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code-

```
sed  's/^$/string/' input > output
```

Comment: `g` is not needed there.